# Angular JS (can i overwrite physical back button on mobiles for my app)

Tags: angularjs

I am creating an app in angular js ,when i open the app it got several partial url like when you click home it will go to home page then in home some other page and so on. index to home to selection page then to payement etc. but when i click back button on page payement it is going to index directly and not to immediate previous page i.e home.this problem is only in Internet explorer 10 for mobile versions.

so can i overwrite back button and give my own action to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real answer to your question is, no.  But there are work arounds.  Your question is basically the same as this post here: [Can JavaScript hook and override browser back and forward buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840457/can-javascript-hook-and-override-browser-back-and-forward-buttons)