# How to restrict the User not go to Previous pages by clicking the Browser's back Button

Tags: javascript

How to stop users to go back to the previous pages upon pressing browsers back button by using javascript.
Any suggestions greately appreciated.**

Thanks and Regards

Bannister

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/12381610/384155

Comment: Why? Do you want to prevent the user from seeing those pages? Is your site designed in such a way that loading those pages would cause some action to be repeated?

Comment: Check this [Demo](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/javascript-disable-browser-back-button/), read [Blog](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/disable-back-button-browser-javascript/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to stop browser back button using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript)

Comment: What did you test so far? A tips is to check out the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page as a new user of this site. :)

Answer (score 2):

Thankfully, it's impossible. You cannot stop the user's back button from working, but you could technically change the url enough times where it becomes pointless to even try using the back button to navigate.

```
// treat the URL changes as a non-external page (the page won't reload)
document.location.href += "?"; 

// Fill up the browser's history
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    document.location.href += "a"; 
    document.location.href = document.location.href.substring(0, document.location.href.length-1)
}
```

This would fill the browser's history with the same page, effectively disabling the back button for any practical use.

Answer (score 2):

Use this on page load, it will stop user on navigating back from page on which it placed.

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">
    function changeHashOnLoad() {
        window.location.href += "#";
        setTimeout("changeHashAgain()", "50");
    }

    function changeHashAgain() 
    {          
        window.location.href += "1";
    }

    var storedHash = window.location.hash;
    window.setInterval(function () {
        if (window.location.hash != storedHash) {
            window.location.hash = storedHash;
        }
    }, 50);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

why don't you just confirm the user action when pressing the back button?

something like

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return "Message here";
}
```

it will prevent user who accidentally click back, forward, or close the window and change the url directly.

Answer (score 0):

By using javascript you can do this.

Refer this,

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/buttons/article.php/3478911

This may helps you

Answer (score 0):

My solution without any confirmations and useless history fill:

Add one dummy history instance when load.
if click on btn, add another.

```
if (window.history && history.pushState) {
    addEventListener('load', function() {
        history.pushState(null, null, null);
        addEventListener('popstate', function() {
            history.pushState(null, null, null);
        });    
    });
}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45844767/13672902