# override browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project in which i need to handle browser back button and on it's click I want to redirect to home page.

I have gone through many post, there are a lot of ways to implement it.

I am wondering, what is the best way to implement it.

If anyone knows similar post, please post the url.

Thanks for help

I have used the following codes:

```
function HandleBackFunctionality()
{
    alert('ckikc')
    if(window.event)
    {
        if(window.event.clientX < 40 && window.event.clientY < 0)
        {
            alert("Browser back button is clicked...");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Browser refresh button is clicked...");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert('clicked')
        if(event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type == 1)
        {
            alert("Browser refresh button is clicked...");
        }
        if(event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type == 2)
        {
            alert("Browser back button is clicked...");
        }
    }
}
window.onbeforeunload = HandleBackFunctionality;
$(document).unload(HandleBackFunctionality);
```

well its not working for me :(

well @kapa said it is a duplicate question, I have mentioned that have googled a lot for this and have seen a lot of solutions for this problem.

my question is not the way to solve it, but the best solution out of available one

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844491/intercepting-call-to-the-back-button-in-my-ajax-application-i-dont-want-it-to

Comment: Users don't like that happening.

Comment: Try google there are some posts about it to dummy this.

Comment: You have to play with HTML5 history API, e.g: http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/stealing-history-api

Comment: @RPM i have limited user for this app

Comment: No i am building CRM for some internal operation, a set of editors will work on it

Answer (score 11):

You can't just override a browser's button's behavior.

Imagine the security problems it would cause if anyone could just "Fake" browser navigation like that. Making users think they navigated to a different site is chapter 1 in phishing for dummies...

However, @[Alek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3420271/alek) [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033040/override-browser-back-button/24033085#comment37048455_24033040) to **[a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844491/intercepting-call-to-the-back-button-in-my-ajax-application-i-dont-want-it-to)**, in the comments on your question, which has a decent alternative (Which is, imo, the best way to achieve the desired result).

Comment: I think OP wanted, redirect to homepage if back button clicked of browser.

Comment: Yea, I got that, but that's not possible. Even if it were, it shouldn't be done. Don't attempt to change a browser's functionalities. If I visit `www.a.com/b`, then navigate to `www.a.com/c`, I expect the back button to load `www.a.com/b`, not `www.a.com`

Comment: @Cerbrus we do it in single page app too, so it should be there if we need it

Comment: @rajansoft1: The question I linked to in my answer, has a answer that explains how single page apps do it. That way has nothing to do with changing the `back` button's functionality, it rather changes the way the site is "registered" in the browser's history, without messing with the browser itself.