# Browser Back Button in Modal Window (Lightbox)

Tags: javascript, browser, lightbox, back-button, modal-window

I am loading content from **WebsiteA.com** into a Modual Window (LightBox). The Modal Window is embedded on **WebsiteB.com** (and not WebsiteA.com).

The user is able to navigate within the Modual Window but if he/she clicks on the Browser Back button the Modual Window closes.

Is there a way to use the **Browser Back button to navigate within the Modal Window**?

Answer (score -1):

Regardless of being on one website or two, it's not possible to override your browser's back button, due to security reasons (e.g. "fake" browser navigation", countless phishing opportunities, etc).

If they were on the same website domain, you could get around this using various methods, such as redirecting to the same URL, but [with a different hash fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1844577/3133680).