# How to capture back button event in Chrome,Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to capture if user clicks on back button of browser(IE, Chrome and Firefox)

I don't want **onbeforeunload** event to be called when user presses the back button of browser

Comment: possible duplicate of [detect back button click in browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359327/detect-back-button-click-in-browser)

Comment: There's already a question about this with an answer on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser

Comment: there are multiple answers for questions like this, please look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Javascript+back+button

Comment: Could you suggest me any one from the link you suggested as i am unable to fine the answer of my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intercepting call to the back button in my AJAX application: I don't want it to do anything!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844491/intercepting-call-to-the-back-button-in-my-ajax-application-i-dont-want-it-to)

Answer (score 3):

**Update** 
In the following function when u click on links you will see the event being fired....now after clicking on any link click back button youll agin c the event being fired.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6by9ude/)**

```js
$(window).bind( "hashchange", function(e) {
  alert()
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://github.com/cowboy/jquery-bbq/raw/v1.2.1/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js"></script>

<nav id="siteNav">
<ul>
<li class="nav1"><a href="#landing" title="Home">Home</a>
<li class="nav2"><a href="#products" title="Products">Products</a>
<li class="nav3"><a href="#about-us" title="About Us">About Us</a>
<li class="nav4"><a href="#sign-up" title="Sign Up">Sign Up</a>
<li class="nav5"><a href="" title="Videos">Videos</a>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Use the `hashchange` event:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(e) {
  // ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this 

but could you please elaborate this.

Comment: @user2078643 Please check :)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing a while ago, but the Back button event of the browsers cannot be listened to.
But, if it could be handy, you can use jQuery (or Javascript) and use the .unload() method

[Jquery .unload() API](https://api.jquery.com/unload/)