# How to detect browser back button click event using polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, back-button

Is it possible to detect that a user entered a page through using the history back button in his browser? Preferably I want to detect this action using polymer.

Comment: No,it's not possible (easily).

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844491/intercepting-call-to-the-back-button-in-my-ajax-application-i-dont-want-it-to

Comment: Do you use Polymer's router?

Comment: yes.. i use <app-route>

Comment: Have you tried the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate)?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably listen on the `popstate` event as documented here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate

This should fire when the back button is clicked, `history.back()` is called, etc.