# Detect if user came back to page via the back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, back-button

Is there a way to detect in Javascript/jQuery if a previously visited page was loaded again (probably from cache) via the back button of the browser?

I don't want to intercept the back button click event. I simply want to detect *if* the page was reloaded with a back button click.

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser).

Comment: You can disable client side cache with appropriate http headers. Look for the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers)

Comment: two questions in one!

Comment: how about restrict user to go to previous page?

Comment: Thanks for the linked questions, I'll go through them. @claudios, I don't want to restrict the user in any way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intercepting call to the back button in my AJAX application: I don't want it to do anything!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844491/intercepting-call-to-the-back-button-in-my-ajax-application-i-dont-want-it-to)

Comment: @Jay Not a duplicate. I don't want to intercept anything -

Comment: Maybe you can use the localStorage. When you press the "Back Button" add an Item to the LocalStorage and get the item at the start of your page. Only works with same domain, no CORS!