# Terminate user session in MVC app when relevant browser tabs closed

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, internet-explorer-11, back

I am currently developing an MVC5/ JQuery/ Bootstrap/ EF6 internet-facing website for a client. Due to the extremely high sensitivity of the data contained by the application, the client has asked if it is possible for the user session to be terminated **when one of the browser tabs containing the application have been closed**. It is imperative that The user must not be able to open a new tab and continue from where they left off - they must login again.

I have searched StackOverflow and found references to scripts using window.beforeunload and window.performance.navigation, and I ended up with the following derivative work, which fails when clicking the back button:

```
var endsession = {

    ValidNavigation: false,

    EndSession: function () {
        var url = '/account/AjaxLogoff';
        if (GetIEVersion() > 0) {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            async: false,
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                utilities.HandleAjaxErrors(xhr, status, error);
            }
        });
        }
        else {
            navigator.sendBeacon(url, '');
        }
    }
};


$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";

    $(window).on("beforeunload", function () {
    if (endsession.ValidNavigation)
        return;

    var navType = performance.navigation.type;

    console.log("NavType: " + navType);

    if (navType !== window.performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD &&
        navType !== window.performance.navigation.TYPE_BACK_FORWARD) {
        endsession.EndSession();
    }
});

// Attach the event keydown to exclude the F5 refresh
$(document).bind('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 116) {
        endsession.ValidNavigation = true;
    }
});

// Attach the event click for all links in the page
$("a").bind("click", function () {
    endsession.ValidNavigation = true;
});

$("form").bind("submit", function () {
    endsession.ValidNavigation = true;
});
```

});

This script fails when using the browser back button. (performance.navigation.type is set to 0 when back is clicked in Chrome, as well as when you input the URL directly)

I have also looked at onpopstate handler - didn't help.

Does anyone know what else I could try? Recommendations for 3rd party libraries are welcome.

Additional constraint: the code must work with IE11 as well as Chrome & Firefox. IE11 is not my choice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hmm, this is tricky. however, the solution which you had found on StackOverflow is suitable for tab close. I suggest you should edit your question to, end session when the browser back button is clicked. I am trying to find a solution for you... as i said this is tricky

Comment: Hi, I don't want the session to end when the back button is clicked. I want the session to end when the tab is closed.  At the moment I am taking a look at whether I can use the HTML5 local session object to detect if a new tab opened - then tell the user they need to login.  However, I expect this is insecure.

Comment: You could try to detect whether user click the browser back button, please refer to [this link](https://www.code-sample.com/2017/10/browser-back-button-event-disable.html) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844491/intercepting-call-to-the-back-button-in-my-ajax-application).