# Handle back/forward button click in browser

Tags: javascript, react-router, browser-history, html5-history, history.js

- I want to console.log(1) if the user clicks on the forward button inside browser,
- **-1** if the user clicks on back button
- **0** if user reloads the page,

This is my code so far, I can not achieve to get -1, why am I doing wrong??

My approach is setting a state inside history object in the component and compare it vs the lenght of the history object...

```
async function handleBackForwardButton() {

    // If none, then zero
    const historyLength = Number(sessionStorage.getItem("historyLength"));
    let { state } = await window.history.state; 
    let position;
    if (state === null || state === undefined) {
      // New entry on the stack
      position = historyLength + 1;
      debugger;
      //  Stamp the entry with its own position in the stack
      window.history.replaceState(historyLength, /*no title*/ "");
      // (2) Keep track of the last position shown
      sessionStorage.setItem("historyLength", String(window.history.length));
      debugger;
      // (3) Discover the direction of travel by comparing the two
      const direction = Math.sign(position - historyLength);
      console.log("Forward should be (1) :" + direction);
      debugger;
      // forward should be (1)
    } else if (historyLength > state) {
      const direction = Math.sign(state - historyLength);
      console.log("Backward should be (-1) :" + direction);
      debugger;
      //One of backward (-1)
    } else if (historyLength === state) {
      const direction = Math.sign(state - historyLength);
      console.log("Reloading page should be (0) : " + direction);
      debugger;
      //Reloading page should be (0)
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener("pageshow", handleBackForwardButton);
  window.addEventListener("popstate", handleBackForwardButton);
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844491/intercepting-call-to-the-back-button-in-my-ajax-application